# Vue js variable including <script>

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to change the text that is displayed in the textarea through Vue.js. The value that I want to pass in is

```
<script>
//run your code
</script>
```

But

```
text = "<script>//runyourcode</script>"
```

will come as an error.

So I believe that Vue.js automatically phrases this as a script that is gonna execute.

Is there any good fixes that I can apply?

Comment: The problem is that when I defining my variable this.text_area = "<ScRiPt></sCrIpt>" would be an error, as vue.js is parasing. So its kinda like python's """text""" and "text"

Answer (score 0):

My solve now is to execute on textarea change

```js
convertHtmlSpecialCharsToReal(){
    this.text_area.replace("&gt",">")
    this.text_area.replace("&lt","<")
}
```